# Refactoring a jquery call

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have wrote some code for a delay on a input button and have a few questions about that..

The code:

```
$('.button-delay').click(function(){
    var delay = $(this);
    delay.prop('disabled', true).parent().removeClass()
        .addClass('button-inactive');
    setTimeout(function() {
    delay.prop('disabled', false).parent()
            .removeClass('button-inactive').addClass('button-blue');
    }, 8000);
});
```

1. Is it necessary to declare the variable 'delay'?
2. Is there a better way to set the state 'disabled'?
3. Is there a shorter way for the methods 'removeClass' and 'addClass'?

Comment: 1. no, but why not? 2. no. why would you need a better way. It's clean, short and effective. 3. what do you mean by shorter way?

Comment: @ Kiro Maybe there is a method thtat's combines addClass and removeClass that I don't know of....

Answer (score 0):

1: no you don't have to. But it is advisable, since you are cahing the jQuery object.

2: no

3: no